# JSON generation and validation libraries in python

Tags: python, json, validation

I have definitions of many JSON objects. They include optional elements and several different types. Also some of the definitions are interconnected. e.g.: if you have a definition of how *'address'* could look like, one element of the *'user'* definition could be *'address'*.

What python library do you use in order to write JSON schemas that help generate generic JSON objects and is also able to validate.

It would especially be nice if I could generate a minimum JSON (only the required elements), a full JSON (all required and optional elements) or even specify the the number of elements generated for lists.

Comment: Although I implemented something that fits my needs for now, feel free to try to answer with existing libraries or other suggestions, regardless of how outdated the question will become ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dictshield](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dictshield) looks good to me.

Source at https://github.com/j2labs/dictshield

Comment: Is good for validating, but I would love the functionality of generating generic examples for a class.

Comment: SchemaObj.to_jsonschema() if that is what you mean

Comment: I don't want a schema, but a generic example of how the json could look like. Random values for all required fields according to their type.